# tooltip with button disabled

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have a form. I do not save the form unless characters are entered. I just want to put tooltip while my button is disabled.

my input :

> ```
>       <input
>         :disabled="isDisabled" value="Test" class="btn btn-success btn-block"
>         @click="test()"
>       />
> ```

my isDisabled func :

```
 isDisabled() { return !this.name || !this.surname;
     },
```

How can I put a tooltip on a button when my button is disabled? If the button is not disabled, I don't want a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated what kind of tooltip do you want to use, so I just used the `title` tooltip.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue 

const App = {
  data() {
    return { toggle: false }
  },
  computed: {
   isDisabled() {
      return this.toggle;  
    },
    title() {
       return this.toggle ? 'This button is disabled!' : '';
    }
  },
  methods: {
    test() { alert('Hello World!') }
  }  
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  Disable: <input type="checkbox" v-model="toggle" /><br/>
  <input
        :disabled="isDisabled" value="Test" class="btn btn-success btn-block" :title="title"
        @click="test()"
      />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```